# positioning fontawesome icons using css

Tags: html, css, flexbox

these are two photos that describe the problem
these are two photos that describe the problem
these are two photos that describe the problem

[this is the orignal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSJ0u.png)

I want the icon to position like this

[but I want it to be like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66r3h.jpg)

I used

```
vertical-align: top;
line-height: 33px;
```

but it is not working, this the full codes
https://jsfiddle.net/8aho9sw5/

```css
.nav3 ul{
    background: rgb(231, 125, 125);
    display:flex;
    width: 800px;
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 6rem;
    padding:0;
    justify-content: space-around;


    
}

.nav3 ul li{
    list-style: none;
    width: 100%;


}

.nav3 ul li a{
    border: 3px solid rgb(25, 0, 255);
    display: block;

    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 22pt;
    padding-top: 3rem;
    padding-bottom: 3rem;
    padding-right: 2rem;
    padding-left: 2rem;

}



.nav3 ul li a:hover{
    background: rgb(95, 155, 125);
}

.home-icon:before{
    vertical-align: top;
    line-height: 33px;

    border: 3px solid rgb(0, 255, 13);
    content: "\f055";
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

    <title>Flexbox Menu Demos</title>
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Various flexible box menu demos from Morten Rand-Hendriksen, staff author at lynda.com"
    />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"
    />
  </head>

  <body>

    <nav class="nav3">
            <ul>
              <li><a href=""><span class="home-icon"></span>home</a></li>
              <li><a href="">contact</a></li>
              <li><a href="">about</a></li>
              <li><a href="">food</a></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
      

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you added more details about what you're trying to accomplish. You should also read the font awesome [documentation](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/styling/power-transforms).

Comment: i updated the post i provided images that describe the problem

Comment: check out my answer @john

Comment: @AmareshSM yes you are right

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what you exactly want. But I guess this link will help you implementing what you want. If you want to align the items on top of the flexbox you can use for example

```
nav-item {
    align-items: flex-start
}
```

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: i updated the post i provided images that describe the problem

Answer (score 0):

Are you expecting like this:

```css
.nav3 ul {
  background: rgb(231, 125, 125);
  display: flex;
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 6rem;
  padding: 0;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.nav3 ul li {
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
  border: 3px solid rgb(25, 0, 255);
}
.nav3 ul li a {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 22pt;
  padding-top: 3rem;
  padding-bottom: 3rem;
  padding-right: 2rem;
  padding-left: 2rem;
}
.nav3 ul li a:hover {
  background: rgb(95, 155, 125);
}
.home-icon:before {
  vertical-align: top;
  line-height: 33px;
  border: 3px solid rgb(0, 255, 13);
  content: "\f055";
  font-family: FontAwesome;
}
span {
  margin-left: -75%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <title>Flexbox Menu Demos</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Various flexible box menu demos from Morten Rand-Hendriksen, staff author at lynda.com" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <nav class="nav3">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">home<span class="home-icon"></span></a></li>
      <li><a href="">contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="">about</a></li>
      <li><a href="">food</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: that is not what I want the list became taller, I want the list to be the same height just the icon move to the bottom

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this. The easiest is to make the `:before` absolutely positioned and set the `top` position to whatever distance you want. (Absolutely positioned elements won't resize their parent's height/width). Remember you need to set the parent to `position: relative` so that the position is based on that.

```css
.nav3 ul{
    background: rgb(231, 125, 125);
    display:flex;
    width: 800px;
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 6rem;
    padding:0;
    justify-content: space-around;


    
}

.nav3 ul li{
    list-style: none;
    width: 100%;


}

.nav3 ul li a{
    border: 3px solid rgb(25, 0, 255);
    display: block;

    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 22pt;
    padding-top: 3rem;
    padding-bottom: 3rem;
    padding-right: 2rem;
    padding-left: 2rem;

}



.nav3 ul li a:hover{
    background: rgb(95, 155, 125);
}

.home-icon {
  position: relative;
  display:inline-block;
  min-width: 60px;
}

.home-icon:before{
    border: 3px solid rgb(0, 255, 13);
    content: "\f055";
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;   
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

    <title>Flexbox Menu Demos</title>
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Various flexible box menu demos from Morten Rand-Hendriksen, staff author at lynda.com"
    />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"
    />
  </head>

  <body>

    <nav class="nav3">
            <ul>
              <li><a href=""><span class="home-icon"></span>home</a></li>
              <li><a href="">contact</a></li>
              <li><a href="">about</a></li>
              <li><a href="">food</a></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
      

  </body>
</html>
```